# How to set bottom constraint of a UITableView to the top constraint of UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I`m working on a Chat App.

What I want to do is auto alignment of the input bar to the tableview. 
When I now open the keyboard, the tableview bottom constraint should change to the top constraint of the input bar, so that I can see the last messages.

I have the following setup in my storyboard:

[image]

[image]

I already tried some code buts not working:

```
self.tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.inputBar.topAnchor)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you ever set the constraint to active? `self.tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.inputBar.topAnchor).isActive = true` ?

Comment: Yes but then I get the following error: ´*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x280403ec0 "UITableView:0x1060fd000.bottom"> and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x28046e500 "XXX.InputBar:0x106a2de50.top"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.´

Comment: Then it seems like the tableView and the input bar aren't in the same view hierarchy. Have they both been added as subviews to the same view before you try to set the constraint?

Comment: i edited my question. Attached my hierarchy structure. Maybe I have the wrong hierarchy.

Comment: inputBar should be in view with tableview

Comment: first add input bar to subView  of self.view and then add bottom constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Create an `IBOutlet` for your `UITableview` bottom constraint:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableviewBottomConstaint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

This will allow us to change the bottom constraint programatically.

2.Set an observer to listen to keyboard events:

```
// listen to keyboard show event
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
// listen to keyboard hide event
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

3.Define the 2 functions that will be called once the keyboard is shown/hidden:

```
// keyboard shown
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
     tableviewBottomConstaint.constant = newValue
}

// keyboard hidden
@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
         tableviewBottomConstaint.constant = newValue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not add or change any constraints. This is the same as for any keyboard with a scroll view behind it. You just watch for the appearance of the keyboard and adjust the table views bottom content inset accordingly.